# inserting arraylist<String> values to sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, for-loop, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have names and id's from listview in 2 different arraylist and would like to store id's and names from arraylist to string and then save them on a button click to sqlite.

The problem with below code is that when 2 items are checked and button is clicked the items are inserting twice. And when the id is set as UNIQUE then on insertion to 3 id's only one is saving in sqlite,...

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 public void addSelected(ArrayList<String> selNames, ArrayList<String> selID) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try{

        for (String str: selID){
            for (String stl:selNames){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_ID, str);
            cv.put(KEY_STATUS, stl);
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_SELECTED, null, cv);

            }
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Problem", e + " ");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should simply try this if both of your array are of same size... and also pass your cv in db.insertorThrow like this

```
public void addSelected(ArrayList<String> selList, ArrayList<String> selID){

        int size = selID.size();

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
       try{
       for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
           cv.put(KEY_ID, selID.get(i));
             cv.put(KEY_STATUS, selList.get(i));
            Log.d("Added ",""+ cv);
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_SELECTED, null, cv);
        }  
db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Problem", e + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the array list without iterating you can do the below method.

/*This code can be used for inserting*/

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();// Create one Jsonobject
json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(items));// put the ArrayList You have in hand by converting that to JSONArray.
String arrayList = json.toString();//Convert json to string
```

/*This code can be used for getting the data*/

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stringreadfromsqlitetable);// Convert the String to JsonObject
  ArrayList items = json.optJSONArray("uniqueArrays");// Conver the jsonObject to Arraylist
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the IDs, and then for each ID iterating all the names, resulting in you inserting all the combinations of the two. Instead, you could iterate the **length** of both lists:

```
public void addSelected(ArrayList<String> selNames, ArrayList<String> selID) {

    int size = selNames.size();

    // Check that both lists have the same size
    if (size != selID.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        // Or some more elegant way to handle this error condition
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_ID, selID.get(i));
            cv.put(KEY_STATUS, selNames.get(i));
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_SELECTED, null, cv);
        }
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Problem", e + " ");
    }
}
```

Note: The call to `db.close()` should probably be in a finally block, not the `try` block. I left it there like it was in the OP because this is not the issue of the question, but you should probably handle that in your real code too.

Comment: @murtazaali care to share some more specific details?

Comment: i will share logcat error message with you please check that

Comment: this is showing in logcat                                                                        01-11 14:00:04.807    6183-6183/ali.murtaza.jsontest E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "null": syntax error
01-11 14:00:04.807    6183-6183/ali.murtaza.jsontest E/Problem﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Selected_table(null) VALUES (NULL)